# about the sentence "The house being built has got most of the shape."

Tags: expressions

I'd like to ask whether the following sentence is correct and how to improve it while retaining the meaning.

- *The house being built has got most of the shape.*

The intended meaning is as follows.

> A house has been being built near your place. It only started 3 weeks ago, but the building has progressed so fast that **now you can see the overall shape of the house**. Until last week, you had no idea as to the shape of the house.

Why I chose that expression over a general one like *The building has progressed a lot* is because I desire to accentuate the fact written in bold in the above paragraph.

Thank you.

Comment: People might say that the structure of the house is almost complete, that it's now possible to see the structure of the house, or that the (overall) shape of the house is now clear..

Comment: What about 'is starting to take/is taking shape'?

Comment: What do you mean by "shape". Are you talking about the floor-plan or do you mean the 3D shape?

Comment: @RonaldSole Thank you for suggesting other good expressions. I think, among what you suggested, *It's now possible to see the structure of the house* comes to my mind.

But, may I ask you for your comment on the original expression I asked about, and also for your thoughts on *It's now possible to see the shape of the house* only with *shape* used instead of *structure*?

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I mean the shape of the house. Does **shape** here not give a clear meaning? Even though I used **shape** to mean the entire form of the house, i.e. what the house looks like, I might have understood the meaning of **shape** wrong as I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @SmartHumanism Yes, **to see the shape** is fine. But NOT **has got most of its shape**. That's not idiomatic.

Comment: @RonaldSole I really appreciate your reply. But as a non-native English speaker, I understand that **fine** does not mean something is entirely correct, if not mistaken. I'd like to ask if the version with *to see the shape* is not as correct and natural as the version with *structure*?

Comment: @SmartHumanism If you were just talking about the foundations of the house, or the floor area, you would refer to the **floor plan**. The shape suggests the structure. You can use shape or structure interchangeably in this context.

Comment: @RonaldSole Actually I mean the overall shape including the windows, walls, roof, fence, etc. Thank you for the additional explanation.

Comment: I asked you what you meant by "shape" and your answer was "I mean the shape of the house".  That suggests to me that you do not fully understand  generality of the word  "shape". You need a more specific word.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Thank you for pointing it out.:) I thought *shape* as in *the shape of the house* represents the general, overall or entire shape of the house automatically. Here, I'd like to ask you if *the entire shape of the house*, not *the shape of the house* properly represents what I mean?

Comment: What @KateBunting said. The relevant idiomatic usage here is *[something, the building] **is taking shape***. Which can be used even of things being "built, created" that don't actually have a "shape" - *The social conventions for a post-Covid world are **starting to take shape***, for example.

Comment: If a house had been fully completed, then we would expect "shape" to refer to its overall shape. Different people would choose to answer in different ways. If a house is in the process of being built, then, at the beginning,  "shape" would refer to its ground plan. Later on, it might refer to its overall 3Dshape. We can't guess from 3 weeks, how far far the build has progressed. I think it best to not use "shape" at all. Choose a different word or words.

Comment: There's also *The [something, the building] is **shaping up** nicely* (it's still in the early stages, but there's already detectable encouraging progress).

Comment: When talking specifically about a house, you could say that "the framing is complete". In construction, the ["framing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_(construction)) is the network of wooden or metal beams that forms the structure of the house.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for teaching me those new useful idiomatic expressions as always!

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica Aha, I appreciate the explanation. But truly at the time I posted, I could see the overall rough shape of the entire 3D shape even including the roof, the space for windows only without the glasses.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Aha, there is **framing**, which I couldn't think of but must mean what I intended very effectively. Thank you very much for the helpful suggestion.

Comment: You even said it: now you can see the overall shape of the house. Better: **The overall shape of the house under construction can now be seen**.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for the enlightening comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of idiomatic usages relevant to OP's context are...

> 1: *The house is **taking shape***
> 2: *It's [**shaping up**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shape-up#:%7E:text=%3A%20to%20improve%20to%20a%20good,Learn%20More%20about%20shape%2Dup) [nicely<sup>1</sup>]*

But it's important to note that both the above forms are almost always used somewhat *metaphorically* (often, in contexts where the thing being referenced doesn't even *have* a "shape"). So most native speakers wouldn't really think in terms of the actual shape (or even the "appearance" in general) if they heard #1 or #2 - they'd just understand that the building work is progressing well.

To convey that as the work progresses, the actual shape of the building is becoming more apparent, you'd have to say something like...

> 3: *The [superstructure](https://www.designingbuildings.co.uk/wiki/Superstructure) is [nearly] complete, allowing us to see the emerging overall shape of the building*

...but you probably wouldn't say that unless you were a builder or architect.

---

<sup>1</sup> Just as [*all petrels are **stormy***](http://www.satiche.org.uk/satiche/sat-0342.htm), *all dudgeon is **high***, and *all fettle is **fine***, almost everything that's *shaping up* does so ***nicely***.

Comment: Thank you very much for the deep insight and delicate approach as to the context and usage. It is always delightful and very helpful to read your answers.

If I may add a brief question about the original expression I suggested in the post: As *The house being built has got most of the shape* definitely seems unnatural, then what happens with **got** substituted with **gained**?

Comment: Nah - you can't save *that* statement by switching from ***got*** to ***gained***. It's just not something an Anglophone would be likely to say. Suppose you last saw your niece when she was 11, but now she's 16 and she's got breasts and other feminine curves. Would you in your own language say anything like *Gosh! You've **got / gained** most of your adult shape!* ? I certainly wouldn't, in English (though I might say *Gosh! You've **filled out**!*).

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I appreciate it. In my native language(Korean), people would not use it for people as it might sound rude, but for things like a house under construction, it is natural to use it as it sounds clear physically.
It is hard time to time to grasp the native-English speaker's hidden understanding that surrounds the bound of which pattern is well composed, as it is sometimes subtle or obscure to non-native English speakers.